# Unable to read text file from any drive

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

For some weird reason, i am unable to read a file from its location. The file exists in the location, however the error says invalid path. According to MS docs, it may also be caused due to permission issues, i tried to place the file in all of my drives and tested i am getting the same error.  Any ideas and solution for this problem.

[image]

Comment: This can happen if the file is on a network share that's visible only to certain users, and you try to access it from a process running as admin, which can mean it can't see the network share.

Comment: @MatthewWatson this is not on network drive. Its my local drive. Any ways using this fixed my problem File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"D:\", "Test.txt")), this was not the  case earlier.

Comment: I would try using Windows Explorer and browse to folder and then open the file with notepad.  Then you can tell if the issue is with the path or the file.

Comment: Very strange... this error makes no sense.  I do not think this has to do with permissions.  The code you showed should be working fine.

Comment: Maybe there were some invisible extra Unicode characters in the string?